# Creating a Form with Dynamically Expanding Text Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a complete noobie to Rails, HTML, CSS and Javascript.

I'm creating a form and I have two requirements:

1) I want text boxes that expand as the text expands in them (see: http://jsfiddle.net/gLhCk/5/)

2.) I want those text boxes to be part of a form that updates objects in a database upon submission.

I've gotten both these pieces working separately -- I can make a text box that expands but doesn't set values in a database, and I can make a form that DOES update a database but doesn't have text boxes that auto-expand.

The difficulty is in combining these two things -- incorporating that Javascript text box into my form that's updating the database.

This is my form that updates the database (with static text boxes):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <div class="row">
      <h3> Background </h3>

      <div class="row">
        <%= f.label :hobbs, 'Hobbies' %>
        <%= f.text_field :hobbies, class: 'fcdzfform-control' %>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript code that works for an auto-expanding textbox:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="txtInput"></textarea>
<script src="jquery.autogrow-textarea" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(#txtInput).autoGrow();
</script>
```

Like I said, I'm a complete noobie to all this stuff, but the impression I've gotten from browsing online is that I need to abandon the .erb form altogether and [make a pure Javascript form](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077176/scripting-jvm-languages/using-javascript-and-forms.html), but I'm still failing to see how to have that Javascript form update the values in my database, like the above .erb form is doing.

And advice / guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See: [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript).

You'll want to separate your Javascript from your html.erb. You can add this Javascript into a relevant file in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder. So, for example:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/sitewide/field-expand.js
(function(){
  $('.expand').autoGrow();
}());

# app/views/product/_form.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <div class="row">
      <h3> Background </h3>

      <div class="row">
        <%= f.label :hobbs, 'Hobbies' %>
        <%= f.text_field :hobbies, class: 'fcdzfform-control expand' %>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to test the above at the moment so, of course, it's untested.
(Also make sure that your jQuery selectors are wrapped in quotation marks e.g. `$('#txtInput')` rather than `$(#txtInput)`)

Comment: When I try that, the class doesn't seem to be loaded properly -- I'm getting the same behaviour without the expandable text box. It might be because I don't really understand the $('.expand').autoGrow(); part. Do I make a file with just that line in it, or do I add that line to my javascript file that renders the expandable text box?

Comment: I'm working under the assumption that `.autoGrow()` is a function which manipulates a DOM object to resize it when called. With that in mind, it can be put into its own .js file in `app/assets/javascripts`. I forgot to make it immediately invoked so I edited my original response for that purpose. If it still doesn't work, I will have to make a project at home to try it which will be in about 2 hours.

Comment: Hmm. Well I copied the Javascript from the first answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784547/jquery-textarea-auto-grow-plugin-cross-browser-compatible                                                                                                     So I just created a file named 'jquery.autogrow.js' and put that in my app/assests/javascripts directory and it worked, though I also had to include a "javascript link tag" to link it.

Comment: Little later than I expected, sorry. That's interesting; is it in your `app/assets/javascripts` directory somewhere and being loaded by your `application.js`? Glad to know you got it working.

Comment: Oh sorry! I meant to say that the javascript textbox worked -- but it still doesn't work from within the form! Sorry for the confusion!